# JSP Search Function Using Mysql not working

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I want to create search option on my project. And it is working when I am searching my records by id or phone_number (in my example named **br_telefona**) but it wont work when I search by first name or last name.

Also phone_number is set to be varchar in database setup same as first name and last name.

Here is my code for search:

```
<%
                    Connection connection = null;
                    Statement statement = null;
                    ResultSet resultSet = null;
                    String id = request.getParameter("q");
                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
                        statement = connection.createStatement();
                        String sql = "select * from buyers where first_name=" + id;
                        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                        while (resultSet.next()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("first_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("last_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("email")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("phone_number")%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                        }
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                %>
```

Above code wont work but following one where I do query by phone_number is working just fine

```
<%
                    Connection connection = null;
                    Statement statement = null;
                    ResultSet resultSet = null;
                    String id = request.getParameter("q");
                    try {
                        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
                        statement = connection.createStatement();
                        String sql = "select * from buyers where phone_number=" + id;
                        resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                        while (resultSet.next()) {
                %>
                <tr>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("first_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("last_name")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("email")%></td>
                    <td><%=resultSet.getString("phone_number")%></td>
                </tr>
                <%
                        }
                        connection.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                %>
```

I also change first name from 'John' to 987654 and did

```
"select * from buyers where first_name=" + id;
```

and it is working.

For some reason request.getParameter("q"); is only working when integer is inputed but not working for varchar.

Database engine is InnoDB, Charset/Collation latin1 / latin1_bin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways in which you can make it work:

1. **Recommended solution:** Use [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of `Statement`. This will help you in two prominent ways: (a) It will protect your application from [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). (b) You do not have to convert the input into text form explicitly by putting `''` around it.

   ```
   String sql = "SELECT * FROM buyers WHERE first_name=?";
   PreparedStatement pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
   pstmt.setString(1, id);
   resultSet = pstm.executeQuery();
   ```
2. **Tactical solution:** Convert the input into text form explicitly by putting `''` around it.

   ```
   String sql = "select * from buyers where first_name='" + id + "'";
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Add quote characters to the query:

```
 String sql = "select * from buyers where phone_number='" + id + "'";
```

Comment: this is vulnerable to sql injection and so not recommened

Comment: @MladenSavic - I recommend you use `PreparedStatement` to simplify your code as well most importantly to avoid the SQL Injection.